# Eclipse & Tomcat - Class loading

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, eclipse-luna

I have recently migrated a Java Client project to a Java Server project, using Tomcat, I have found that project library dependencies *may* be broken.

Ordinarily I include the Libraries into the Java Build Path via the Eclipse menu option. I store the Libraries in the project `\lib` folder.

When I do this via a Tomcat server build I get errors on the library objects. I understand that you may need to load the libraries separately via;

```
Class.forName(classString);
```

However when I do this a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception is thrown. So I figure I'm loading the dependencies wrong. But how do I do that via Eclipse & Tomcat?

I should also mention that I am using the "Run On Server" feature of eclipse, just in case this changes anything regarding different requirements for running in Eclipse and deployment.

Comment: Is \lib included in the classpath?

Comment: The `.Jar` files that are used in the project are included via the Java Build Path menu in the project properties. Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the whole eclipse aspect: As you mention tomcat and a server project: You probably have a web application. Web applications, when deployed, include all the `jar`-files that are contained in `WEB-INF/lib` at runtime.

When everything works at compile time, eclipse is happy with the setup. When you get the NoClassDevFoundError at runtime (in tomcat), you most likely need to give tomcat a hint where to find the jar files. And that will be `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Additionally, that folder is already included in the Eclipse build path so there is no need to include any `.Jar` files manually.